# Could not resolve placeholder 'jwt.secret' in string value "${jwt.secret}"

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-boot

I have configured the property source using the annotation:

`@PropertySource(value = {"classpath:application.properties"})` but I still get error saying `Could not resolve placeholder 'jwt.secret' in string value`

```
@PropertySource(value = {"classpath:application.properties"})
public class JwtAuthenticationTokenFilter extends AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter {

    @Value("${jwt.header}")
    private String tokenHeader;

    public JwtAuthenticationTokenFilter() {
        super("/**");
    }
}
```

dispatcher-servlet:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
       xmlns:jpa="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-4.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.rsc."/>
    <mvc:annotation-driven />

    <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/"/>

    <bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
        <property name="basenames">
            <list>
                <value>classpath:validation</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>

<!--    <bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <property name="locations">
            <list>
                <value>classpath:application.yml</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>-->

    <!--    <security:authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
        <security:authentication-provider user-service-ref="userDetailsServiceImpl">
            <security:password-encoder ref="encoder"></security:password-encoder>
        </security:authentication-provider>
    </security:authentication-manager>-->   

    <!--<bean id="userDetailsServiceImpl" class="com.rsc.service.UserDetailsServiceImpl"></bean>-->

    <bean id="JwtAuthenticationTokenFilter" class="com.rsc.security.JwtAuthenticationTokenFilter">
        <property name="authenticationManager" ref="authenticationManager" />
        <property name="authenticationSuccessHandler" ref="jwtAuthenticationSuccessHandler" />
    </bean>

    <security:authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
        <security:authentication-provider ref="jwtAuthenticationProvider" />
    </security:authentication-manager>

    <bean id="encoder" class="org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder">
        <constructor-arg name="strength" value="11"/>
    </bean>

    <!-- Configure the data source bean -->
    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="${jdbc.driverClassName}"/>
        <property name="url" value="${jdbc.url}"/>
        <property name="username" value="${jdbc.username}"/>
        <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}"/>
    </bean>

    <!-- Configure the entity manager factory bean -->
    <bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.rsc.model"/>
        <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
            <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter"/>
        </property>
        <property name="jpaProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
                <prop key="hbm2ddl.auto">create</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.id.new_generator_mappings">false</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <!-- Configure the transaction manager bean -->
    <bean id="transactionManager"
          class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory"/>
    </bean>

    <!-- Enable annotation driven transaction management -->
    <tx:annotation-driven/>

    <jpa:repositories base-package="com.rsc.repository"/>

    <bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/"/>
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

Application properties:

```
jdbc.driverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
jdbc.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/rs_education
jdbc.username=admin
jdbc.password=admin

jwt:
  header: Authorization
  secret: my-very-secret-key
logging:
  level:
    org.springframework.security: DEBUG
server:
  port: 8888
spring:
  resources:
    chain:
      enabled: true
management:
  security:
    enabled: true # set to false to disable 'default' Spring Boot security
```

Answer (score 6):

If you want to use yaml your file should be called application.yml and you can use this format.

```
jwt:
  header: Authorization
  secret: my-very-secret-key
```

If you want to use properties style format your file should be called application.properties and you use the following format:

```
jwt.header=Authorization
jwt.secret=my-very-secret-key
```

Comment: You can use YAML for your config files in spring-boot, so you're not right.

Comment: @KrzysztofAtłasik yes or course, I've clarified my answer.

Answer (score 2):

As documentation states, you could use [YAML](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-properties-and-configuration.html#howto-use-yaml-for-external-properties), but you have to call your file `application.yml` instead of `application.properties`.

You also have to add [snakeyaml](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.yaml/snakeyaml/1.17) to your dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

I found a new detail: if you use multi module, then this properties will write in main `yaml/properties`. Do not use module's `yaml/properties`. It cannot be scanned.

Answer (score -1):

It should be below;

```
@PropertySource(value = {"classpath:application.yml"})
public class JwtAuthenticationTokenFilter extends AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter {

    @Value("${jwt.header}")
    private String tokenHeader;

    public JwtAuthenticationTokenFilter() {
        super("/**");
    }
}
```

fixed anotation.

```
@PropertySource(value = {"classpath:application.yml"})
```